# Unable to load factories from location [META-INF/spring.factories]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created spring boot application by using Spring Initializr which generate below pom.xml

```
.....
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>testproject</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I am trying to run it getting below error. I am  not sure why it is failing on spring.factories file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load factories from location [META-INF/spring.factories]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:418)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at 
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:140)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:122)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:136)
    ... 16 more
```

My application is simple one and don't have any configuration, I am not sure what I need to add into spring.factories file.

Comment: What version of java are you using to package?

Comment: same error i am also getting when try to run "java -jar <jar file name>". i am using java 8 version and latest spring boot version

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, when creating the same project with spring initializer.

You did not specify how you tried to start your project, try this:

```
mvn clean install
mvn spring-boot:run
```

from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

`SpringFactoriesLoader` tries to load `spring.factories` but failed to find the file from `META-INF/spring.factories`. As `spring.factories` is used for [Auto-configured Beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html), you need to check if you have used `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ConditionalOnClass` or `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` kind of annotations. Make sure you know the annotations you are using.

A workaround is putting a blank file `spring.factories` under `META-INF` folder.